# Why Date_ADD interval is not working in this case

Tags: mysql

I have got  Date picker in my front end where a User can select a Date and Symbol and get its historic prices

From Selected date i am fetching next  30 days records and this is my query

**(Assume user has selected Dec 01 2015)**

```
SELECT *
FROM historical_data
WHERE current_day BETWEEN DATE_ADD('2015-12-01', INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND '2015-12-30'
  AND symbol_name = 'YESBANK'
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3693b/9

Could you please tell me why its fetching no records

Answer (score 3):

DATE_ADD('2015-12-01', INTERVAL 30 DAY) will return `2015-12-31`

Your current query is which always return **false**.

```
SELECT *
FROM historical_data
WHERE current_day BETWEEN  '2015-12-31' AND '2015-12-30'
  AND symbol_name = 'YESBANK'
```

Answer (score 1):

Your condition is always false:

```
WHERE current_day BETWEEN DATE_ADD('2015-12-01', INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND '2015-12-30'
<=>
-- WHERE current_day BETWEEN '2015-12-31' AND   '2015-12-30'
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3693b/14/0)**</kbd>

Use correct date range where start date <= end date instead:

```
WHERE current_day '2015-12-01' AND '2015-12-30'
```

or:

```
WHERE current_day BETWEEN DATE_ADD('2015-12-30', INTERVAL -29 DAY) AND '2015-12-30'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use between, you mist only give the start and end date like:

```
SELECT *
  FROM historical_data
  WHERE  current_day 
    BETWEEN '2015-12-01' AND '2015-12-30'
  AND symbol_name  = 'YESBANK';
```